# Using C# and asp read and write xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, xml

Any useful link will help me to understanding the entire process and help me to complete this task.

Comment: Why xml? you can make objects and insert it by row by row or by table value parameter

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the docs on MSDN, there are examples at the bottom.

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx
```

for getting a dataset from XML see this MSDN article

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx29c3yd.aspx
```

the final part - regarding the writing back to multiple tables can be see from this walk through on MSDN

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4esb49b4.aspx
```

Comment: I have xmlstring and I need to parse the value in a dataset. I didn't see any example in the link.

Comment: No the first is about getting the odd bit of XML in your original post into XML and shaping it as required, which it look like you've done. For getting XML to data see the second link.

Comment: Thanks code Uniquely. It helps; I still don't get anything writing back to two sql tables.

Comment: Final link deals with the whole life cycle of read, Edit using a DataGrid and Finally a Write back to SQl - You could adapt the latter approach to get an idea on how to write your content to DB.

Comment: Read the final walk through for saving data to multiple tables  ...

Comment: Thank you so much Code Uniquely. These links are very useful.